# Specific request for Youtube API from shell

Tags: bash, shell, api, youtube

**Using bash, I try to retrieve information from my YouTube channel.**

```
curl -G https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search -d part="snippet" -d q="THISISMYCHANNELID" -d key="THISISMYKEY"
```

**This works quite well, but it doesn't give me the 2 information I need:**

-The number of subscribers of the channel

-The number of uploaded videos of the channel

I went trough the official documentation ( https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/ ) but I didn't find any relevant query, though I am sure there is a solution for that.

Comment: 1: It doesn't contain the second part of my question about the number of uploaded videos.  (probably they should be done with 2 different queries)

2: That answer worked with the previous version of Youtube API but it is now depricated as it is seen on the comment section.

Comment: Unless the information is in the output and you are asking how to extract it, this question doesn't really have anything to do with `bash`.

Comment: I would like to know the 2 queries and how to extract them from the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call [Channel List API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) and use `snippet=statistics`. From [channel model](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels) it will give :

```
"statistics": {
    "viewCount": unsigned long,
    "commentCount": unsigned long,
    "subscriberCount": unsigned long,
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": boolean,
    "videoCount": unsigned long
}
```

Using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) & [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), you can use :

```
curl -G -s https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels \
     -d part="statistics" \
     -d id="UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw" \
     -d key="your_key" | \
     jq -r '.items[].statistics | (.subscriberCount, .videoCount)'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works very well.